# Delete rows and column from a numpy array, given information to delete is in another vector array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have the following code:

```
deleterowandcolumns = np.array([0,3])

original = np.array ([
                 [1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [5, 6, 7, 8],
                 [9, 10, 11, 12],
                 [13, 14, 15, 16]
])
```

The rows and columns to delete is contained in the `deleterowandcolumns` array. Manually, I deleted the specified rows and columns like:

```
deleted = np.delete(original,(0,3), axis=0)
deleted = np.delete(deleted,(0,3), axis=1)
```

The following required output is obtained:

```
 [[ 6  7]
 [10 11]]
```

However this method is very manual and does not use the `deleterowandcolumns` array at all. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `deleterowandcolumns` as the second argument of `np.delete`. I couldn't find a consistently faster alternative.